# javascript semantics

Tags: javascript

I am trying upgrade my javascript programming skills ( or lets say my programming skills period : ) )

so I am trying to understand some semantics :

in the first line what does the "?" mean as well as the minus sign in "-distance"

in the second line what does '+=' or '-=" mean?

```
 el.css(ref, motion == 'pos' ? -distance : distance)

animation[ref] = (mode == 'show' ? (motion == 'pos' ? '+=' : '-=') : (motion == 'pos' ? '-=' : '+=')) + distance;
```

thank you

Comment: Want to improve your programming skills? After you undestand what it does, rewrite it in a **readable** way that will not confuse the next coder. (btw, it looks like utter nonsense - it is playing with +/- of a number, and then subtracts or add it, seems pointless)

Comment: yes, like this, `el.css(ref, -1 * ('pos' === motion) * distance)`, :P (just a joke)

Comment: @Dan: you want `(1-('pos'===motion)*2)*distance`.

Comment: yes, you're right.  the readability is so good even I can interpret it, :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a ? b : c` means "`b` if `a` is true, `c` otherwise".

`-a` means `a`, negated.

`a -= b` and `a += b` mean `a = a - b` and `a = a + b` respectively. However, in your example these operators aren't actually present in the code, they are just text strings the code is manipulating.

Comment: In his example, the `-=` and `+=` are actually strings.

Comment: @Brian: yeah, just spotted that :)

Comment: hmm... `-=` and `+=` as strings... I smell an `eval` somewhere ;)

Answer (score 1):

? is the ternary operator

it equals

```
if( motion == 'pos' ) { return -distance; } else { return distance; } // - is just negating the distance value
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `(a ? b : c)` means "return `b` if `a` is true, and return `c` if `a` is false."
2. The minus sign means negation.
3. The `'+='` and `'-='` are simply strings.

Answer (score 0):

What you call 'semantics' is actually programming language syntax. It's very basic knowledge that can be acquired easily by googling a bit or looking at Wikipedia.

Here's the JavaScript article on Wikipedia, and here's the answers on your [first (conditional operator section)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Conditional_operator), [second (Arithmetic)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Arithmetic) and [third (Assignment)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Assignment) questions within the same article. RTFM please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that will answer the ? question (? is a shorthand evaluation operation).
http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_comparisons.asp

+= would be used to increment a value (also shorthand)
e.g.

```
i = i + 1; is the same as i += 1;
```

the same applies to -=

Comment: technically I guess this is correct, but `'-='` is not the same as simple `-=` (it's a string sent to jQuery's css function, but is doing this behind the scenes, so I didn't vote you down)